# Convert numeric format Date to as.Date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I want to convert Birth.Date column into a format as.Date

```
 $ Birth.Date           : num  38525 39425 39679 39675 39740
```

Comment: Study `help("as.Date")`, in particular the examples at the bottom.

Comment: Where did those values come from? If they came from an Excel file it's probably better to fix the loading code so the fields are treated as dates from the start. For example, [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf) will read the date values as Posixct  as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663890/how-to-read-dates-from-a-excel-files-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an `Excel` date.
If this is the case, use `as.Date` with `origin = "1899-12-30"`:

```
as.Date(c(38525,39425, 39679, 39675, 39740), origin = "1899-12-30")

#"2005-06-22" "2007-12-09" "2008-08-19" "2008-08-15" "2008-10-19"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `excel_numeric_to_date` from `janitor` package

```
library(tibble)
library(janitor)

# vector with your values
date_vector <- c(38525, 39425, 39679, 39675, 39740, 38525, 39425, 39679, 39675, 39740)

# transform to date
excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(as.character(date_vector)), date_system = "modern")
```

Output:

```
 [1] "2005-06-22" "2007-12-09" "2008-08-19" "2008-08-15" "2008-10-19" "2005-06-22" "2007-12-09" "2008-08-19" "2008-08-15"
[10] "2008-10-19"
```